# Nominalization for being "not convex" and "not coercive"

Tags: functions, terminology

Having a function `f` which is not convex or not coercive (*coercive =* [*`|x|` goes to infinity implies `f(x)` goes to infinity*](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koerzitive_Funktion)). What is the correct nominalization for these properties? I suppose something like

```
non-convexity of f
non-coercivity of f
```

Additionally, is it correct to say

```
f is non-coercive
f is non-convex
```

Some notes:

- I have migrated this question from [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/175360/nominalization-for-being-not-convex-and-not-coercive?noredirect=1#comment366308_175360).
- I only found "non-coercivity" in the context of vector fields, so it doesn't seem to be correct. But what is the correct nominalization then?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Non-coercive and non-convex may not be interpreted as "neither convex nor coercive". Usually "non" indicates "not necessarily" rather than "certainly not". For example, a "noncommutative ring" is a ring that is not necessarily commutative - commutative rings form a subcollection of noncommutative rings. This usage varies, though.

Comment: Oh, thank you. That is interesting to know.

Comment: Hmmm... what about "non-negative numbers"? Or "nondecreasing curve"? I would interpret both as "certainly not"-situations.

Comment: Although I cannot answer your question, I agree with you regarding "non". I think that the examples of @M.Vinay are the exception, not the rule.

Comment: Yes, I agree. Maybe it is a usage more common in algebra. But I still suggest that you always make sure what the norm is.